# Highcharts server timeout/empty image

Tags: ubuntu, highcharts

We have a highcharts export server v3 currently built on an Ubuntu VM.

At present (using the demo page), we are sometimes given .png files that are 7 bytes, and contain no image in them. Sometimes however, rather than being given any file we get the following error:

> "Timeout converting SVG, is your file this big, or maybe you have a syntax error in the javascript callback?"

Running phantomJS from the command line gives us a populated chart, but we get nothing from the demo page. Any  advice would be greatly appreciated.

My app.properties file looks as follows:

```
#### phantomjs properties ####

# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777

# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = /usr/bin/phantomjs

# location of convert script used by phantomjs, optional to leave the script property empty, than it's using the script located in: /WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js. This is tested in TOMCAT, but sp$
script = /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/highcharts-export/WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js

#### connect properties used to connect with phantomjs running as HTTP-server ####
# all values in milliseconds

# specifies the timeout when reading from phantomjs when a connection is established
readTimeout = 6000

# timeout to be used when opening a communications link to the phantomjs server
connectTimeout = 500

# the whole request to the phantomjs server is scheduled, max timeout can last to this value. This is because in java you can't rely on the above two timeouts.
maxTimeout = 6500

#### Pool properties ####

# number of phantomjs servers you can run in the pool.
poolSize = 5

# The pool is implemented as a BlockingQueue. When asking for a phantom server connection and nothing is available, it waits for the number of milliseconds defined by maxWait
maxWait = 500
```

Comment: If you are using a browser which one is it. We found a problem with IE sending in a much larger SVG string than any other browser which was greater than the allowed length for the java server we use.

Comment: What do you have your POST character length set to in your java server and what is the POST message length that Chrome is sending?

Comment: When you are trying to use Highcharts exporting server do you encounter that bug? If yes, recreate issue on jsFiddle please.

Comment: Any luck? Im facing the same issue